# React modal not closing onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, state

I have a list of multiple `components` that each opens up a `Modal` on click event. I am passing the method `onHide` to each `Modal` that should close the modal once the close button is clicked, but nothing happens.

I logged the click and the click is registered, but the state is not changing when `modalClose` is called in `Seances.js`. What am I doing wrong?

**Seances.js**

```js
class Seances extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        modalShow: false
      };
    }

  render() {
    const seances = this.props.seances;
    const handleDeleteUser = this.props.handleDeleteUser;
    let modalClose = () => this.setState({ modalShow: false });

    return (
      <Fragment>
        {seances && seances.length > 0 ? (
          seances.map(({devices, interval, startDate, endDate, status}, index) => (
            <div className="card" style={{marginBottom: '7px', width: '100%'}} key={index} onClick={() => this.setState({ modalShow: true })}>
              <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title">Seansi nr: {index}</h5>
                <p className="card-text">Seadmed: {devices}</p>
                <p className="card-text">Algus aeg: {startDate}</p>
                <p className="card-text">Lõpp aeg: {endDate}</p>
                <p className="card-text">Intervall: {interval}</p>
                <p className="card-text">Staatus: {status}</p>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="close float-right"
                  aria-label="Close"
                  onClick={() => handleDeleteUser(index)}
                >
                  <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <ResultModal
                  id={1}
                  show={this.state.modalShow}
                  onHide={modalClose}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))
        ) : (
            <div>
              <p>Aktiivsed seansid puuduvad</p>
            </div>
          )}
        </Fragment>
      );
   }
}

Seances.propTypes = {
  handleDeleteUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  seances: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      devices: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      interval: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      startDate: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      endDate: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      status: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
  )
};

export default Seances;
```

**ResultModal.js**

```js
class ResultModal extends React.Component {
  changeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.devices]: event.target.value });
  };

  getPickerValue = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.onHide}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            Seance nr: 1
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div>
            <form>
              {/*First row*/}
              <MDBRow>
                <MDBCol md="4">
                  <h4 id="section1"><strong>Result</strong></h4>
                  <p>Integer eleifend massa nec sem rhoncus tristique. Mauris pulvinar justo vitae
                     nisi pretium tincidunt. Nulla dolor nibh, porta ut fringilla vel, maximus at mauris.
                     Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut aliquam
                     malesuada turpis eu luctus. In eget sapien quis urna cursus tempus.
                     In eu placerat elit, ut tristique justo</p>
                </MDBCol>
              </MDBRow>
              <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.props.onHide}>
                Close
              </Button>
              <MDBBtn color="success" type="submit" className="float-right">
                Convert to File
              </MDBBtn>
            </form>
          </div>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

ResultModal.propTypes = {
  onHide: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  show: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default ResultModal;
```

Comment: For each `seance` you have a <ResultModal> which are all controlled by the same boolean `modalShow`. This will make all modals appear together, and disappear together. If they're at the same location they will be stacked on top of each other and only the modal for the last `seance` will be visible.

Comment: Thats what I thought also, but how should I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not call this code into the render method:

```
let modalClose = () => this.setState({ modalShow: false });
```

Here a [**doc**](https://itnext.io/react-setstate-usage-and-gotchas-ac10b4e03d60) which said:

> **render**
>
> Calling setState here makes your component a contender for producing infinite loops. render should remain pure and be used to conditionally switch between JSX fragments/child components based on state or props. Callbacks in render can be used to update state and then re-render based on the change.

Instead, you have to change your modalShow via your `handleDeleteUser` for instance, or in the click of your button close.

```
...
handleDeleteUser (e) {
   ...
   ...
   this.setState({ modalShow: false });
}
...
```

Comment: What? That's just a function declaration. setState is not called in the render method.

Comment: I am not sure how the `handleDeleteUser` fits here, but I moved the `let modalClose = () => this.setState({ modalShow: false });` outside the render method and `binded` it to the `Seances.js` class. After doing that I still get the same result.

Comment: `handleDeleteUser` is just an example of how you can change the state of `modalShow`.